# Side navigation menu like Facebook app With Expandable listview

Tags: android

I would like to create a app there is side navigation menu.In this there is expandable listview.
I have looked facebook lib.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for a drawer navigation. Full tutorial is available here:

http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

Comment: Thanks Curly. No I am not looking for navigation drawer. In navigation drawer action bar is static. I need action  bar should slide with screen like in face book app only difference in my app and face book expandable list view. In my app there is exapandable list view instead of list view.

Comment: Well there should be no problem with following the example and changing the listview for an expandable list view. I'm not sure about the Action bar sliding though I'll have to have a look at the FB app